# Crear un tema nuevo para las notificaciones Firebase desde aspx.net

Tags: asp.net, firebase, push-notification

Estoy haciendo una app para Android y quiero poder enviarles notificaciones desde un servidor asp.net.

Desde la consola de Firebase de Google funciona correctamente, pueden enviarles una notificación a todos los dispositivos que usen la aplicación.

Según he leído no es posible enviar este tipo de notificiación desde fuera de la consola, por lo que se me ha ocurrido que todos los dispositivos se suscriban a un tema, y enviar la notificación al tema.

El problema es que quiero crear el tema desde el servidor, y no tengo ni idea.
He probado con esto:

```
    private void crearTopic()
        {
        try
            {
            var applicationID = "AAAARq_rfdY:APA92bH4GeOlB2p............";
            string deviceId = "c9yessCNTc:APNN91bE................";//Mi movil
            string url = @"https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/"+ deviceId+"/rel/topics/minuevotema";
            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("url");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", applicationID));

            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                    {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                        {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                            {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            //Response.Write(sResponseFromServer);
                            string respuesta = sResponseFromServer;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
            {
            string cad = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Pero salta una excepción, supongo que es por los ":" del ID del dispositivo.

Alguien puedo echarme una mano? o decirme alguna pagina de ejemplo?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Cuá. es la excepción?

Comment: El mensaje que muestra la excepción es: "URI no válido: no se puede determinar el formato del URI."

Comment: Parece que habia un problema en esta linea:
string url = @"https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/"+ deviceId+"/rel/topics/minuevotema";

Cambiandola por esta: 
string url = string.Format("https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1/{0}/rel/topics/j2app-devices", deviceId);

La excepcion no salta. 

Voy a esperar a ver si el tema lo ha creado.

Comment: @Juanjo toda la información debe ir en tu pregunta, dale click en [edit], ya que los comentarios son temporales. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

mi app móvil la construí utilizando Firebase con Xamarin Forms
te adjunto el código que utilizé en mi app web para enviar notificaciones e

```
 public void SendPushNotification(string deviceId)
    {

        try
        {

            string Server_Key = "AAAApYKXRw8:APA91bGm4FvAZTnULA1pM-qj9twpE_xutZDlLXjyiLpdpP1seNsHa0nGwvFclKsx75Kney-3WkBbCAVHeqXFbYr3QCeXWAIjSSgho2rQOd40H-Z2MjDpb5VxgKgswRKQt";

            string senderId = "71086XX047";

            // string deviceId = "cVfegfXs1K8:APA91bHUHAxQQ1j9geVrcL65j2lI6xaHS9Fm64561s-DOCTHiX0EDZhuGkdCcLJ5rji2XLshtL9ldtJ02hnjzw134l7BCRizZj22kjBu6ysaptQ596l";

            WebRequest tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            var data = new
            {
                to = deviceId,
                notification = new
                {
                    body = "Hola",
                    title = "Notificacion1",
                    sound = "Enabled"

                }
            };
            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(data);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", Server_Key));
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse())
                {
                    using (Stream dataStreamResponse = tResponse.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStreamResponse))
                        {
                            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();
                            string str = sResponseFromServer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string str = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Nota: deviceId es el token que me entrego firebase en la app móvil.

Espero que te sirva, saludos!

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, pero eso lo que hace es mandar una notificación a un dispositivo, pero no crea un tema, o mejor dicho, no suscribe el dispositivo a un tema.